# check work on kruskal's and prim's algorithm?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image: problem]

from that i got

1st is kruskal's and 2nd is prim's

i'm still unsure the way to do these algorithims can you give me a quick check?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you’re supposed to be working with the subgraph induced by the labelled vertices, your first spanning tree is correct for Kruskal’s algorithm, but we can’t tell whether you derived it correctly without knowing the order in which you chose the edges. You should have chosen $df$ and $ec$ first, in either order, followed by $ab$ and $bc$ in either order, followed by $ef$. The total weight is $9$, however, not $7$.

You should have got the same spanning tree from Prim’s algorithm, no matter at which vertex you started. If you start at $a$, for instance, the first edge that you choose should be $ab$; this is followed, in order, by $bc$, $ce$, $ef$, and $fd$. If you start at $f$, the order is $fd$, $fe$ (because $3<4$, $ec$, $cb$, and $ba$.